# Why is the electric field phase shifted in this circular plane wave?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, polarization, plane-wave

The $x$-component of a circular polarized plane wave is

$$ E_x(\vec r,t)=E_0\cos\left(\frac{w}{c}(0.6y-0.8z)-wt\right) $$

With only this given, we can devise the total electric field as

$$ \vec E(\vec r,t)=E_0 \left[\cos\left(\frac{w}{c}(0.6y-0.8z)-wt\right) \hat x \pm \sin\left(\frac{w}{c}(0.6y-0.8z)-wt\right)(0.8 \hat y + 0.6 \hat z) \right]$$

When looking for the total electric field, we first need to define the wave vector, which is $\vec k = \frac{w}{c}(0.6\hat y - 0.8\hat z)$. We know that $\vec k \cdot \vec E = 0$, which is already satisfied for the $x$-component of our electric field.

Since we want $\vec k \cdot \vec E = 0$ to be satisfied in the $y,z$-directions aswell, we need to add a term to our total electric field which becomes zero when multiplied by $\vec k$, this is represented by $(0.8 \hat y + 0.6 \hat z)$ in our answer, since $\vec k \cdot (0.8 \hat y + 0.6 \hat z) =0$. What I don't understand in this question is why the second term needs to be a sine-term, and not just be attached to the cosine? The answer would then look like

$$ \vec E(\vec r,t)=E_0 \left[\cos\left(\frac{w}{c}(0.6y-0.8z)-wt\right) (\hat x + 0.8 \hat y + 0.6 \hat z) \right]$$

But this is not a correct answer, because according to my lecture notes, $E_{y,z}$ needs to be phase shifted 90 degrees, which is done using sine instead of cosine. Any help understanding why this is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: calculate the magnitude of the total electric field at a fixed point as a function of time. For a circularly polarized field this should be constant; for a linear polarization it will oscillate all the way down to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution gives a linearly polarized plane wave, not a circularly polarized one.

> , i don't understand why we need to phase shift our electric field (the y and z components of E) through the sine-term

This is what it means to be circularly polarized.

Think about a simpler situation where the field only has x and z components. Instead of the x and z components both going to zero at the same time, one is 90 degrees out of phase from the other, so $\vec{E}$ traces a circle over time:

[image]

(image [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Circular.Polarization.Circularly.Polarized.Light_Left.Hand.Animation.305x190.255Colors.gif))

The wave in your example is the same as this, only the basis vectors are rotated so that propagation is not exactly along one particular axis.

As a key point, the magnitude of $\vec{E}$ is constant in time for a circularly polarized wave, but it varies between 0 and $E_0$ for a linearly polarized wave.

Comment: ok, thanks. if you have any intuition in regards to _why_ that is, i would love to understand more. i've done some research but i can't seem to get a hang of it, i don't understand why we need to phase shift our electric field (the y and z components of E) through the sine-term